# using localStorage in html5

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

```
<form>
<input name="Team1" id="team1" type="text" value="Team1?">
<button id="dostuff" value="Go">Go</button>
</form>

<div id ="nicteamcolumn">Team: </div>

<script>
$('#dostuff').click(function(e) {

var team1 = $('input[name="Team1"]').val();

if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            if (localStorage.teamlist) {
                localStorage.teamlist= localStorage.teamlist + team1;

            }
            else {
            localStorage.teamlist = " ";    
            }

            $('#nicteamcolumn').html("Team:" + "<br>" + localStorage.teamlist + "<br>")
      }
}
</script>
```

Basically, when the button is clicked, I am taking the input from Team1, add it to `localStorage.teamlist`, and changing the html of `#nicteamcolumn` to `localStorage.teamlist`

I am getting a weird output the first time I click the button. It prints the value for team 1 a ton of times over and over. The 2nd click and on seem to be working fine as well as when I close the page and coming back and keep adding to the list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Your button as it is submits the form when you click it, because buttons by default are submit buttons. Since your form has no action parameter, submitting it causes a reload of the page. Change your button to have an attribute type="button", then see what happens when you click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It prints the value for team 1 **a ton of times over and over.** The 2nd click and on seem to be working

That's because the `localStorage` object is **persistent**. Even when the source code of your script changes, the `localStorage` values will still exist. You might be confusing `localStorage` with [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#sessionStorage).

### Fixing your code:

- Fix the syntax error by placing a `);` after the last `}`.
- [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is not a function, please do not make it look like one, by removing the parentheses.
- The very first time, **nothing** will print, because you're adding a space instead of the value of Team1.
- Instead of setting the property directly, it is recommended to use the `.getItem` and `.setItem` methods, to avoid mistakes as using conflicting key names.
- Your current "list" is a set of a concatenated string. That's not easily maintainable. Either use an unique separator to separate your values, or use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to store real arrays.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BXSGj/

Code (using JSON):

```
$('#dostuff').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting
    var team1 = $('input[name="Team1"]').val();
    if (typeof Storage !== "undefined") {
        // Will always show an array:
        var teamlist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('teamlist') || '[]');
        teamlist.push(team1);
        localStorage.setItem('teamlist', JSON.stringify(teamlist));
        $('#nicteamcolumn').html("Team:<br>" + teamlist.join('<br>') + "<br>");
    }
});
```

Using a separator (only showing different lines):

```
        var SEP = '|'; // Separator example
        var teamlist = (localStorage.getItem('teamlist') || '').split(SEP);
        teamlist.push(team1);   // Still the same
        localStorage.setItem('teamlist', teamlist.join(SEP));
```

To remove the stored items, use the `localStorage.removeItem` method:

```
localStorage.removeItem('teamlist');
```

See also: [Compability table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#Browser_compatibility) for the `Storage` object.